# Negative binomial model cannot find starting position to sample

Tags: python, bayesian, mcmc, pymc3

I am having difficulties running a PYMC3 model when the observed data is discrete. Oddly, if the observed data contains the value zero (0.), the model will run.

I've read in other posts that that suggest using 
`start = pm.find_MAP(fmin=scipy.optimize.fmin_powell)` but that does not resolve the issue.

```
pymc3.__version__ = '3.0'
theano.__version__ = '0.7.0.dev-RELEASE'
numpy.__version__ = '1.8.0rc1'
Python 2.7.10
```

See [iPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/markdregan/ffa0e62d7a020391e826)

The code and error are below.

```
import pymc3 as pm

data = [6.0,12.0,12.0,46.0,5.0,11.0,11.0,39.0,4.0,10.0,25.0,11.0,8.0,5.0,10.0,2.0,30.0,21.0]

with pm.Model() as model:
    alpha = pm.Uniform('alpha', lower=0, upper=100)
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower=0, upper=100)

    y_pred = pm.NegativeBinomial('y_pred', mu=mu, alpha=alpha)

    y_est = pm.NegativeBinomial('y_est', 
                                mu=mu, 
                                alpha=alpha, 
                                observed=data)

    start = pm.find_MAP()

    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(20000, step, start, progressbar=True)
```

The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b9f2264fccfc> in <module>()
     14                                 observed=data)
     15 
---> 16     start = pm.find_MAP()
     17 
     18     step = pm.Metropolis()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymc3/tuning/starting.pyc in find_MAP(start, vars, fmin, return_raw, disp, model, *args, **kwargs)
     79     if 'fprime' in getargspec(fmin).args:
     80         r = fmin(logp_o, bij.map(
---> 81             start), fprime=grad_logp_o, disp=disp, *args, **kwargs)
     82     else:
     83         r = fmin(logp_o, bij.map(start), disp=disp, *args, **kwargs)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/optimize.pyc in fmin_bfgs(f, x0, fprime, args, gtol, norm, epsilon, maxiter, full_output, disp, retall, callback)
    775             'return_all': retall}
    776 
--> 777     res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
    778 
    779     if full_output:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/optimize.pyc in _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, gtol, norm, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, **unknown_options)
    830     else:
    831         grad_calls, myfprime = wrap_function(fprime, args)
--> 832     gfk = myfprime(x0)
    833     k = 0
    834     N = len(x0)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/optimize.pyc in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    279     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    280         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 281         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    282 
    283     return ncalls, function_wrapper

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymc3/tuning/starting.pyc in grad_logp_o(point)
     74 
     75     def grad_logp_o(point):
---> 76         return nan_to_num(-dlogp(point))
     77 
     78     # Check to see if minimization function actually uses the gradient

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymc3/blocking.pyc in __call__(self, x)
    117 
    118     def __call__(self, x):
--> 119         return self.fa(self.fb(x))

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymc3/model.pyc in __call__(self, state)
    397 
    398     def __call__(self, state):
--> 399         return self.f(**state)
    400 
    401 class LoosePointFunc(object):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    862                     node=self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    863                     thunk=thunk,
--> 864                     storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    865             else:
    866                 # old-style linkers raise their own exceptions

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.pyc in raise_with_op(node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    312         # extra long error message in that case.
    313         pass
--> 314     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    315 
    316 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    850         t0_fn = time.time()
    851         try:
--> 852             outputs = self.fn()
    853         except Exception:
    854             if hasattr(self.fn, 'position_of_error'):

ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[0] = 1, input[4].shape[0] = 18)
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{Composite{Switch(i0, i1, Switch(i2, Switch(i3, i1, i4), i1))}}(TensorConstant{(1,) of 0}, TensorConstant{(1,) of 0}, Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x}.0, TensorConstant{[  6.  12... 30.  21.]})
Toposort index: 33
Inputs types: [TensorType(int8, vector), TensorType(int8, (True,)), TensorType(int8, (True,)), TensorType(int8, (True,)), TensorType(float64, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (18,)]
Inputs strides: [(1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (8,)]
Inputs values: [array([0], dtype=int8), array([0], dtype=int8), array([1], dtype=int8), array([0], dtype=int8), 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Sum{acc_dtype=float64}(Elemwise{Composite{Switch(i0, i1, Switch(i2, Switch(i3, i1, i4), i1))}}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Probably might help others if you provide versions of the libraries in use.

Comment: Good point @recluze - I've added versions to post

Comment: This turned out to be a bug: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/842